# How to change the display text of md-select box while maintaining the model?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I am using Angular material library directive `md-select` to show a bunch of country codes to my users. In the selection menu i want to show the country name and country dialing code but once a country is selected i want to display only it's dialing code in the select box.

ex. on choosing `India (+91)` option the text of select box should be `+91`.
The code i am using is as follows.

```
<md-select ng-model="ctrl.selectedCountry" ng-model-options="{trackBy: '$value.code && $value.name && $value.prefix'}">
        <md-option ng-repeat="country in ctrl.countries" ng-value= "{{ country }}" >
                    {{ country.name }} ({{ country.prefix }})
        </md-option>
</md-select>
```

I can't figure how to achieve this because this way leads to the exact same display text as in the `md-option` tag on selection.
Is there a way to specify the display text template based on the selected value without changing the `ng-model` binding?

Comment: There is no _strainght forward_ method to do so..But you can play around **md-on-close** which accepts _Expression to be evaluated when the select is closed_

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
<md-select ng-model="ctrl.selectedCountry" ng-model-options="{trackBy: '$value.code && $value.name && $value.prefix'}">
        <md-option ng-repeat="country in ctrl.countries" ng-value= "{{ country }}" >
                    {{ctrl.selectedCountry.prefix === country.prefix ? country.code : (country.name + ' (' + country.prefix + ')')}}
        </md-option>
</md-select>
```

Comment: Doesn't work when item is selected and you again go and view options. Next time you view options, it will not appear for already selected item.

Answer (score 1):

Since angular-material 1.0.8 there's `md-selected-text`, so you could try:

```
<md-select md-selected-text="ctrl.selectedCountry.prefix" ng-model="ctrl.selectedCountry" ng-model-options="{trackBy: '$value.code && $value.name && $value.prefix'}">
  <md-option ng-repeat="country in ctrl.countries" ng-value= "{{ country }}" >
    {{ country.name }} ({{ country.prefix }})
  </md-option>
</md-select>
```

Comment: Is it possible to switch between the md-selected-text and the options selected based on how many options actually are selected? If you have more than 3 options selected you show the md-selected-text, if not you show the options selected.

Answer (score 1):

My solution for md-select with multiple.  It's a nice css trick and works pretty well.

```css
.option-hack {
  display: none;
}

md-option .option-hack {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<md-input-container class="md-block">
  <label>Some Label</label>
  <md-select multiple
             ng-model="ctrl.array">
    <md-option ng-value="item" ng-repeat="item in ctrl.items" ng-selected="item.isOn">
      Always shown
      <span class="option-hack">Hidden on main</span>
    </md-option>
  </md-select>
</md-input-container>
```